# Flutter HTTP POST request / code 400 error

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, post

I am trying to make a POST request and I keep getting a 400 error code. I cant figure out why. I have everything I need and it seems to all be in order. Here is the code where I am making the call:

```
                                  TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.black,
                                        minimumSize: Size(130.w, 40.h)),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      await ApiService().createNewTag(textController.text, companyId);
                                      // print(companyId);
                                      // print(textController.text);

                                      Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getTagsProfile(
                                          int.parse(companyId)));
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Save',
                                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                          .bodyText1
                                          .override(
                                            fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                            fontSize: 18.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
```

Here is the code for my POST API call:

```
    Future createNewTag(String tag, String companyId) async {
    final createTagUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.CREATE_NEW_TAG_URI);
    final response = await http.post(createTagUrl, headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AppConstants.TOKEN,
      'X-API-KEY': AppConstants.API_KEY
    }, body: {
      'company_id': companyId,
      'tag': tag
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: If you a getting a 400 error code, then you are most likely doing something wrong. Confirm that you are using the right base URL, and endpoints. CONFIRM and be sure, don't assume, mistakes happen.

You should also wrap you async code in a `try and catch block` so that when things go wrong, you can trace what went wrong. Doing this should be a norm.

Comment: Thanks @davidn, I found the solution late yesterday evening. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a time of reflecting upon my own sanity and searching the internet, I came upon a thought. If this is not being interpreted by the API correctly, it could potentially cause me to get the error that I am. So I decided to change the way I was sending the body portion of my POST api call. I also thought to try to json.encode the body before it being sent. Low and behold, I found the solution!

```
    Future createNewTag(String tag, String companyId) async {
    final Map body = {'company_id': companyId, 'tag': tag};
    final createTagUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.CREATE_NEW_TAG_URI);
    final response = await http.post(createTagUrl, body: json.encode(body), headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AppConstants.TOKEN,
      'X-API-KEY': AppConstants.API_KEY
    });
    print(createTagUrl);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```